# 2 vectors form a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I was told that 2 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ define a plane. However, if vectors themselves are defined by their "head" or coordinate points, wouldn't 2 vectors define 2 points and therefore a line?

Are we using the "body" of the arrow to define the inclination of the plane? Or are we assuming that the plane goes through the orgin (if that's the case, why are we making that assumption?)

Comment: You want to imagine that the vectors have the same tail.  If the two vectors are linearly independent, then this yields three points that are not co-linear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *span* of two linearly independent vectors forms a plane in $\Bbb R^3$. This means that if $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, then
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{v,w\}=\{\lambda_1 v+\lambda_2 w\in\Bbb R^3:\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Bbb R\}
$$
is a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

This is a special case of the fact that if $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ are linearly independent vectors in a vector space $V$, then $\Span\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace of $V$.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's not the 2 vectors themselves, it's all the possible combinations of the scaled versions of those vectors?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff Yes!

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense!

Comment: @jeremyradcliff another way to put it is that the plane is "made out of" the "heads" of all possible combinations of scaled versions of the vectors, with the tail fixed at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you mean by a *vector*. One way to define/think about a vector is a direction and a magnitude, that is an arrow.

If you let that arrow start at the origin in a coordinate system, then the coordinates to the head will correspond to the vector. Of course, vectors can start other places and be considered equal. That is, when we say that a vector is given by a point, we say that if you take the vector and let it "start" at the origin, then the "head" will end up at the point.

Now given a vector $\vec{v} = (x,y, z)$, you have a line spanned by that vector: $\mathbb{R}\vec{v} = \{(ax,ay, az): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$. This line consists of all the *points* $(ax, ay, az)$ where $a$ is any real number.

Likewise, if you have two (linearly independent) vectors $\vec{v} = (x_1,y_1, z_1)$ and $\vec{w} = (x_2, x_2, z_2)$, then the space spanned by those two vectors is a plane:
$$
\mathbb{R}\vec{v} + \mathbb{R}\vec{w} = \{(ax_1 + bx_2, ax_2 +by_2, az_1 + bz_2) : a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.